# Sharepoint 2010 Excel Calclation Error

Tags: sharepoint-server

I am using Sharepoint 2010 in Form Environment. Getting below error, when we call the Excel workbook in browser, randomly. We have used a package called `xldisplay` to view single sheet in browser. Excel View in browser working fine.

Any suggestions?

> Error Message from Parse Excel: Some error while processing! at
>   Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.WebServices.ApiShared.ExecuteServerSessionMethod(Boolean
>   hasSessionId, String sessionId, CoreServerSessionMethod coreWebMethod,
>   String name) at
>   Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.WebServices.ExcelService.GetRange(String
>   sessionId, String sheetName, RangeCoordinates rangeCoordinates,
>   Boolean formatted, Status[]& status) at
>   ExcelDisplay.Layouts.xldisplay.ParseExcel(SPWeb _spWeb, String
>   _strWorkBookPath, String _strSheetName, Nullable`1 _blnIsAdminMode)